# Debugging signal handling in multithreaded application

Tags: c, multithreading, debugging, signals

I have this multithreaded application using pthreads. My threads actually wait for signals using sigwait. Actually, I want to debug my application, see which thread receives which signal at what time and then debug it. Is there any method, I can do this. If I directly run my program, then signals are generated rapidly and handled by my handler threads. I want to see  which handler wakes up from the sigwait call and processes the signal and all.

Answer (score 1):

The handy [strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) utility can print out a huge amount of useful information regarding system calls and signals.  It would be useful to log timing information or collect statistics regarding the performance of signal usage.

If instead you are interested in getting a breakpoint inside of an event triggered by a specific signal, you could consider stashing enough relevant information to identify the event in a variable and setting a [conditional breakpoint.](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_set_a_conditional_breakpoint?)

Comment: Is it possible to use eclipse and use breakpoints in my threads. I am not sure if this will work. The signals are generate continuously and I block them first and then synchronously access them using sigwait

Comment: Well, running the program under a debugger (and especially breakpoints) may significantly change the timing patterns of asynchronous events anyway.  If you want to get an accurate picture of how the timing actually works I would run it without the debugger attached.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things you may try with gdb is set breakpoints by thread (e.g. just after return from sigwait), so you know which thread wakes up:

```
break file.c thread [thread_nr]
```

Don't forget to tell gdb to pass signals to your program e.g.:

```
handle SIGINT pass
```

You may want to put all of this into your *.gdbinit* file to save yourself a lot of typing.

Steven Schlansker is definitely right: if that happens to significantly change timing patterns of your program (so you can see that your program behaves completely different under debugger, than "in the wild") then **strace** and logging is your last hope.
I hope that helps.